# How force in one direction of the rope transfer to another end when there are multiple contact with other object

Tags: friction

Sorry for the long title, I really don't know much about physics so I don't know how to phrase it better. I am making a grappling hook in a game for someone else. My main occupation and previous education has been mostly to do with maths.

So the case here is Let's say I launch a grappling hook, if I proceed to walk around ,rope would obviously wrap itself around different objects if said objects do exist in the scene. I have already made the "rope" and it knows when it has "intersected" with whichever edge of the object given the player movement through linear algebra. Therefore I know where the intersections are. Here are some sample pictures.[image]

However this wouldn't work for the obvious reason that intersections of rope and objects are not stationary in the real world. It should slide along the edge even leave the edge given the force vector exerted by the player on the other end of the rope(hook side of the grappling hook is stationary in my case). I would love to know if there is some equation for this even just how force is conducted through the rope. I do have to apologize in advance that I really don't know much about physics I stopped learning it at year 10 so any symbols that doesn't exist in mathematics I would need an explanation. Here are a few images to show you how it currently operate. As you can see it only takes into regard what the intersection of rope and walls are and make a new segment of the rope currently. I am trying to add some physics into it as it is important for the gameplay. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the surface you are sliding the rope over. It namely depends on **friction**.

Friction $f_k$ (we are talking about kinetic friction $f_k$ as opposed to static friction $f_s$) is a force that holds back and tries to stop sliding. How big that friction force is depends on the roughnesses of both rope and surface and on how those two materials interact, usually combined into one **friction coefficient** $\mu_k$. The formula for kinetic friction is then simply:

$$f_k=\mu_k n$$

$n$ is the normal force, in other words how hard the rope is pressed onto the surface. $n$ should be not-too-difficult to find from force-balance considerations in your case (Newton's 1st law in directions perpendicular to the surface where the rope is pressed on to the surface). But the geometry might be tricky.

The issue most likely is to estimate $\mu_k$. Of course you can assume perfectly 100% smooth corners (equivalent to having a pulley placed at each corner) which gives $\mu_k=0$ and thus no friction. Or you can pick a "normal" value (a quick Google search gives many examples of e.g. steel-on-steel, steel-on-ice, ice-on-ice etc.)

Now, you naturally need a couple of assumptions / idealizations. For example that the rope is massless. And that the rope is incompressible. And that the sharply bended corners of the rope behave just like any other part of the rope.

Also, there might be an issue with how much of the rope that actually touches the surface. The formula above is independent on the contact area, but only for an evenly distributed $n$. On a rope passing a corner i would expect the normal force to gradually decrease with distance from the corner where it peeks. A simplification is to consider the corner as causing one friction force with the above formula and the any other force causes a new friction force. The total pull due to friction is then the sum of all these. Corners close to each other may interfere with this and the simplification wouldn't hold any more.

Comment: Thank you so much for helpinng me out. I still have trouble understanding the normal force. Since it is a rope wrap around the corner. how do I calculate the normal force? What I have trouble understand is which part of the original force vector exerted by the player would translate to the surface after the contact. Also in which order do we go about calculating the force on each segment of the rope, by segment I mean each piece of the rope separated by a sharp turn.

Comment: @RockyZhang You could simplify the normal force to point directly at a 45 degree angle away from the corner. The size of it then depends on the tension in the rope on either side of the corner (the normal force equals the resulting force caused by those tensions and will be pointing inwards at the same angle). The tensions in either of those rope pieces are equal under no-friction circumstances and will thus equal the initial pulling force, but when friction is present you must add (subtract) friction from the pulling force at each section. The tension therefore progressively decreases.